# My MacBook Pro is connected to wifi but is not opening any web page both from Safari and Chrome

Tags: safari

I have checked my TCP which is set for DHCP and is automatically, in DNS I have only one ip which is 10.0.1.1 and my proxies are not checked. I don't know how else check if all is good. Please help

Comment: use ping in  terminal ping google.com

Comment: This is hard to answer without more details. Are you on a LAN? Or behind a DSL modem? The DNS looks fishy, where does it come from?

Comment: Well I don't know where to find that out Peter if I'm on LAN or DSL. How to check that?  The whole story is that I would use this MacBook only in us before and just a month ago my bf flu to Peru. He has told that neither safari nor chrome re not opening any web pages. Firefox works but super slow. Literally forever to load a page. Since than he has not used it. I just got it back and now trying to fix it ;(. I'm assuming with automatic configurations my MacBook had the Ip was picked up there.